# Change text onblur with javascript price range dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dropdown works if you select a price, but if you want to modify the price in the text box

```
<input name="min_price" type="text" class="min_input form-control" placeholder="Min Price" onchange="javascript:void(0)">
```

it does not update. How can you do an onblur change when manually typing in the price?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28teLgbv/)

```js
function nFormatter(num, digits) {
    var si = [
        { value: 1, symbol: "" },
        { value: 1E3, symbol: "k" },
        { value: 1E6, symbol: "M" },
        { value: 1E9, symbol: "G" },
        { value: 1E12, symbol: "T" },
        { value: 1E15, symbol: "P" },
        { value: 1E18, symbol: "E" }
    ];
    var rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
    var i;
    for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (num >= si[i].value) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}

$('.dropdown-menu.ddRange')
        .click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

function disableDropDownRangeOptions(max_values, minValue) {
    if (max_values) {
        max_values.each(function() {
            var maxValue = $(this).attr("value");

            if (parseInt(maxValue) < parseInt(minValue)) {
                $(this).addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
}

function setuinvestRangeDropDownList(min_values, max_values, min_input, max_input, clearLink, dropDownControl) {
    min_values.click(function() {
        var minValue = $(this).attr('value');
        min_input.val(minValue);

        var minInput = nFormatter(minValue, 1);
        min_values.val(minValue);
        document.getElementById('price_range1').innerHTML = '$' + minInput + ' to ';

        disableDropDownRangeOptions(max_values, minValue);

        validateDropDownInputs();
    });

    max_values.click(function() {
        var maxValue = $(this).attr('value');
        max_input.val(maxValue);
        var maxInput = nFormatter(maxValue, 1);
        if (maxInput == 0){
            var maxInput = 'No Max';          }
        document.getElementById('price_range2').innerHTML = '$' + maxInput;

        toggleDropDown();
    });

    clearLink.click(function() {
        min_input.val('');
        max_input.val('');
        document.getElementById('price_range1').innerHTML = "Price Range";
        document.getElementById('price_range2').innerHTML = "";

        disableDropDownRangeOptions(max_values);

        validateDropDownInputs();
    });

    min_input.on('input',
            function() {
                var minValue = min_input.val();

                disableDropDownRangeOptions(max_values, minValue);
                validateDropDownInputs();
            });

    max_input.on('input', validateDropDownInputs);

    max_input.blur('input',
            function() {
                toggleDropDown();
            });

    function validateDropDownInputs() {
        var minValue = parseInt(min_input.val());
        var maxValue = parseInt(max_input.val());

        if (maxValue > 0 && minValue > 0 && maxValue < minValue) {
            min_input.addClass('inputError');
            max_input.addClass('inputError');

            return false;
        } else {
            min_input.removeClass('inputError');
            max_input.removeClass('inputError');

            return true;
        }
    }

    function toggleDropDown() {
        if (validateDropDownInputs() &&
                parseInt(min_input.val()) > 0 &&
                parseInt(max_input.val()) > 0) {

            // auto close if two values are valid
            dropDownControl.dropdown('toggle');
        }
    }
}

setuinvestRangeDropDownList(
        $('.investRange .min_value'),
        $('.investRange .max_value'),
        $('.investRange .freeformPrice .min_input'),
        $('.investRange .freeformPrice .max_input'),
        $('.investRange .btnClear'),
        $('.investRange .dropdown-toggle'));
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    left:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
.max_value{
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 30px;
}

.price_Ranges {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.price_Ranges a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
    color: #6f6e6e;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.price_Ranges a.max_value {
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.price_Ranges a.min_value {
    padding-right: 22px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.price_Ranges a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: #E5E4E2;
}
.price_Ranges a:hover {
    background: #0074e4;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btnClear {
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
input.inputError,
input.inputError:focus {
    border-color: #e2231a;
    background-color: white;
    color: #e2231a;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #F7BDBB;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #69899f;
    border-color: #425766;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="padding:50px;">
    <li class="nav-item">

        <button id="min-max-price-range" type="button" class="selectpicker select-btn  dropdown-toggle searchParams dropdown-toggle btn btn-default navbar_btn" data-toggle="dropdown" title="price range" aria-expanded="false"> <span id="price_range1" id="navbar_title"></span><span id="price_range2" id="navbar_title">Price Range</span>  <b class="caret"></b></button>

        <div class="span2 investRange">

            <div class="dropdown-menu ddRange" role="menu" style="width: 295px;padding: 10px; top:auto;">
                <div class="rangemenu">
                    <div class="row freeformPrice">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <input name="min_price" type="text" class="min_input form-control" placeholder="Min Price" onchange="javascript:void(0)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <input name="max_price" type="text" class="max_input form-control" placeholder="Max Price" onchange="javascript:void(0)">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="price_Ranges rangesMax col-md-6" style="padding:0px;">
                        <a class="max_value" value="" href="javascript:void(0)">No Max</a>
                        <a class="max_value" value="100000" href="javascript:void(0)">$100k</a>
                        <a class="max_value" value="300000" href="javascript:void(0)">$3000k</a>
                        <a class="max_value" value="500000" href="javascript:void(0)">$500k</a>
                        <a class="max_value" value="1000000" href="javascript:void(0)">$1M</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>

                    <div class="price_Ranges rangesMin col-md-6"  style="padding:0px;">
                        <a class="min_value" value="" href="javascript:void(0)">No Min</a>
                        <a class="min_value" value="50000" href="javascript:void(0)">$50k</a>
                        <a class="min_value" value="100000" href="javascript:void(0)">$100k</a>
                        <a class="min_value" value="250000" href="javascript:void(0)">$250k</a>
                        <a class="min_value" value="500000" href="javascript:void(0)">$500k</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btnClear">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link">Clear</a>
                </div>
            </div>  </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can use `onblur` attribute on each `input` to set the handler for the `blur` event

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <input name="min_price" type="text" class="min_input form-control" placeholder="Min Price" onchange="javascript:void(0)" onblur="document.getElementById('price_range1').innerHTML = '$' + this.value + ' to ';">
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
 <input name="max_price" type="text" class="max_input form-control" placeholder="Max Price" onchange="javascript:void(0)"  onblur="document.getElementById('price_range2').innerHTML = '$' + this.value;">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuoedtq2/